# Run protractor test script in multiple nodes (os platform) via selenium grid

Tags: protractor, selenium-grid2

I am currently trying to run Protractor test script using selenium grid. My goal is to distribute Protractor test scripts to multiple nodes running under different flavor of OS. It should also run different parts of test script in parallel to save execution time. Current setup works when I use webdriver-manager to distribute test with multiple instances, but webdriver-manager would let me use only one node. I know it's possible to overcome this issue with selenium grid, but I am having following errors test console:

```
node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:26
  constructor(opt_error) {
                         ^
WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at WebDriverError (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:26:26)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
    at ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
    at ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27
    at ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)
    at Builder.build (./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
    at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:42:27)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:203:37)
    at ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:293:21
    at _fulfilled (./node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (./node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (./node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at ./node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Also, selenium node that I registered complains with following messages:

```
$ java -jar /Users/user/Desktop/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar   -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="./node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.21" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=ANY,platform=MAC,maxInstances=20" 
14:40:17.078 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
14:40:17.126 INFO - Adding browserName=chrome,version=ANY,platform=MAC,maxInstances=20
14:40:17.515 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.74-b02
14:40:17.515 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
14:40:17.521 INFO - v2.52.0, with Core v2.52.0. Built from revision 4c2593c
14:40:17.570 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
14:40:17.570 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
14:40:17.570 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:40:17.570 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
14:40:17.630 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
14:40:17.650 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
14:40:17.650 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
14:40:17.669 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
14:41:32.968 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rootElement=*[ng-app], count=1, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=4, shardTestFiles=true}]])
14:41:32.977 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rootElement=*[ng-app], count=1, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=4, shardTestFiles=true}]
14:41:32.998 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'user-M-C19J', ip: '10.128.164.26', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'user-M-C19J', ip: '10.128.164.26', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    ... 14 more
14:41:33.002 WARN - Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

this is my current configuration:

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.21',
capabilities: {
'rootElement': '*[ng-app]',
'browserName': 'chrome', // chrome, firefox, or phantomjs
'shardTestFiles': true,
'maxInstances': 3  
}
```

I ran the following command line to launch hub:

```
java -jar /Users/xxx/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role hub
```

and following is for running node:

```
java -jar /Users/xxx/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Chrome driver is under: /node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.21

Has anyone successfully configure protractor with selenium grid?

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver_manager is bundled in npm as a quick solution for starting server and is not a comprehensive solution as Selenium Grid. Grid should be used for all professional distributed execution environment.
Check this [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2420) for response from Julie

Webdriver-Manager doesn't have options for hub & node

And regarding Protractor with Selenium Grid, I did use local Grid and also Sauce Labs. 
You should pass the chrome driver property when initializing the node.

> java -jar /Users/xxx/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role node -hub http://*******:4444/grid/register/ -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Users/<>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe

The protractor Conf - chromedriver option is not passed over grid and it works for only webdriver-manager.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've commented out chromeDriver property from the protractor.conf file and added the chrome driver property while initializing node like you mentioned above then ran the command. I was able to make node register with hub, but when I ran the protractor test script, it still complains the same error message. do you have any idea?

Comment: I also posted an error message from the node. please take a look at the error output from the posted question